# Bluetooth settings won't open Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am trying to open the Bluetooth settings in order to pair a device, but I cannot open the Bluetooth settings window even though Bluetooth is ON. Did anyone come across this and found a solution?

EDIT - I can't open other settings as well (Wi-Fi, battery)

[image]

Comment: This worked for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420736/settings-window-does-not-open-in-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following commands worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run these 2 commands in your terminal :

1. `sudo rmmod btusb`
2. `sudo modprobe btusb`

This should probably fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, It didn't work, and I can't open battery and Wi-Fi settings too.

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, you might be able to debug it by entering `gnome-control-center` in the terminal. I did and got the error `version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)`. Once I saw that it was easy to fix with `conda install -c conda-forge gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because our Settings icon is not visible on left side of the window.Ue below commands to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```