# Settings window does not open in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, settings, gnome-control-center

I've been an ubuntu user for the last 5 years, I newly upgrade from 20.1 to 22.04 and my settings aren't working, I tried to install the gnome-control-center but the terminal reply me with the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 3.10.5-1+focal1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to make the settings work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 48):

Probably this was due to a recent update. At least this was the problem for me.

The following procedure solved my issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Then I restarted `gnome-control` and reopened the display with the following commands:

```
gnome-control-center display
gnome-control-center
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: One would think this issue of display settings would be resolved in 2023. I confirm that the reinstallation of the gnome-control-center did the trick.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: "I hope this helps.": you bet!! ... it did in my case...Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the power setting issue. I set it to the `performance` mode instead of `Balanced` or `Power Saver`.

Try changing by:

`$ powerprofilesctl set balanced`